# After the modification of ApplicationResources.groovy the main page stops running

Tags: grails

I´ve tried to modify my application resource file (ApplicationResources.groovy) and my entry page stops working. I got this following error:

> URI
>       /grails/
>   Class
>       java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
>   Message
>       No module found with name [application]

"No module found", but the module already exists. I just have changed it:

```
    modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
    }
}
```

to:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource url:'js/application.js'
        resource url: 'css/main.css'
    }
}
```

This css also already exists in notified path.

I have no idea how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

I know this post i dead, but, if anyone else is looking I thought I could help.  If you want to include a resource you can define a custom resource definition.

The "application" module is the default configured module.  It includes the application javascript file.

The detailed instructors for the resource plugin are available, and this site is the "Resource Declaration" page, http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/guide/3.%20Declaring%20resources.html, and it will show you what is happening with the resources and how to implement them.

Hope that helps someone out there.

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to restart the server. If that doesn't work, stop the server, execute `grails clean` then start it again. By the way, the `url:` property is only necessary if you're including other properties (which you're not), so you can shorten the above to:

```
modules = {
    application {
        resource 'js/application.js'
        resource 'css/main.css'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Don. But didn´t work. The page that it occurs is the entry page generated by Grails, the index.gsp. I didn´t any kind of modification to this page.